# Counting number of ones and zeros inside char array

Tags: c, customization

I'm trying to make customized code to count number of zeros and ones in every element of char type array after converting element to binary form. Here is my code. If there is any better way to write it please mention it. This work for embedded system. Thanks in advance.

```
void counter(unsigned short bits_num, short sizeof_array, char array[]) {

    unsigned char zero = 0, one = 0;

    while (bits_num && sizeof_array) {
        if (array[sizeof_array - 1] & 1)
            one++;
        else
            zero++;
        array[sizeof_array - 1] = array[sizeof_array - 1] >> 1;
        bits_num--;

        if (!bits_num) {
            bits_num = 8;
            printf("zeros number is %i, ones number is %i in element: %x\n",
                   zero, one, sizeof_array - 1);
            sizeof_array--;
            zero = 0;
            one = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this while (bits_num&&sizeof_array){ mean? And also whar does this parameter bits_num mean?

Comment: bits_num is the number of bits inside char type for example

Comment: @YasserMohamed  It is known and equal to CHAR_BIT . Moreover the representation of the type char does not contain padding bits.

Comment: @Olaf You are wrong. From the C Standard "...signed char shall not have any padding bits"

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ok, found it. thanks. (why did they not put it with the unsigned char remark.

Comment: @Olaf 6.2.6.2 Integer types p.#2.

Comment: @YasserMohamed-- you may find [this selection of methods for counting set bits](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive) interesting.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow found it already. It stll leaves `char` itself to deduction from 6.2.5p15 . "the character types shall have no padding bits" might have been too clear:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are problems in your code:

- what is the `bits_num` argument supposed to represent? It seems to be the number of bits per array element, but you force it back to `8` after the first byte.
- why does `sizeof_array` have a type `short`? The array might have a larger size, especially on modern systems.
- right shifting a signed type is calling for trouble: you should use `unsigned char` as the `char` type may be signed by default on some architectures and right shifting negative values is implementation defined.
- modifying the array to count the bits is a bad side effect.

Here is a simpler version:

```
void counter(int bits_num, size_t array_size, const char *array) {

    for (size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        unsigned char x = (unsigned char)array[i];
        int bits = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < bits_num; j++) {
            bits += x & 1;
            x >>= 1;
        }    
        printf("zeros number is %d, ones number is %d in element %x\n",
               bits_num - bits, bits, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: *Left-shifting* a negative number is undefined: *Right-shifting* a negative number is implementation-defined.

Comment: i would add to your answer that you could eliminate branching by using: "one += (x & 1);" and then calculate zero as "zero = bits_num - one;"

Comment: @Mehdi: I was trying to preserve the OP's logic, but indeed counting the ` bits only is much simpler.

Comment: I was preparing the answer then i refresh and saw your's, then i wanted to contribute to it instead, sorry if i offended you. on more thing you have to wrap x & 1 inside parenthesis because + is executed before &

Comment: @Mehdi: no offense at all.  The parentheses are not needed as the `+=` binds like the `=` operator.

Comment: If we're talking about efficiency, why not use `__builtin_popcount()` or the equivalent your compiler provides?

Comment: @EOF: whether `__builtin_popcount()` can be used or not depends on the value of `bits_num`. Using a simple look up table is quite efficient too.

Comment: @chqrlie As far as I can see, you can use `__builtin_popcount()` by  `AND`ing with a mask derived from `bits_num` before.

Comment: @EOF: that's true, and if we were looking for raw performance, there would be many more ideas to develop, but I tried to keep the above code portable and simple enough to understand for newbies to learn from.